# itemize indentation

Tags: indentation, itemize

I think you guys know the answer, I tried a lot (`descripition`, `enumerate`) but it all didn't work, so heres my problem: The text after the long items has the correct indentation on the first two lines, but the last, the 3rd. row, has a wrong indentation, so it is far to left, and this looks stupid,

here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item short item
     \item short item
     \item short
     \item long item the problem here is, this has the wrong indentation
     \item long item, also here, the same
   \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: ok, I modified it
its not using any packages, it is just the problem, that the indentation is not correct, Latex doesn't accept those long items, the indent is then in the 3rd. row to much left, under the item point ...... thanks a lot

Comment: Your code (& output) looks fine, I can't see the problem

Comment: the problem is the following, the text looks like:
. text text text text text text

and this is broken correctly when the second line begins, but the 3rd. starts to much left, the indentation is wrong?

Comment: Are you by chance expecting the formatted output to follow the indention of your source `\item`s?

Comment: @Halifaxinus: can you include an image of the output you are getting, as it looks fine to me also.

Comment: There are nothing wrong in the MWE. The ouput  should be as showed by Shigur.

Answer (score 2):

For me, everything looks correct. See:

[image]